# How to access all files in app data folder

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm googling and debugging for days now, and did not find a solution, how to access all files on google drive in the folder created by my application.

I'm using v3 API with non sensitive permission drive.file. This means I can create folders, and create and list files in it. But I only see (list) files which were created by the application. If the user copies some other file into the folder created by the application, it is invisible for the application, and I did not manage to set permission either on the web client, nor in the application.

I don't want to set all files permission to my app, since I don't want to access anything in the user's drive, just in my folder, but there I would like to see also files, the user copied there.

The files are settings/schema export of my application, which the user might move between users with different google account.

Is it possible? How could I list all files in the app data folder? Is there a way to share a file with an application on google drive? Can the user do it manually (like copy the file there, and then set some kind of permission to the application, so it can list/download that file)

Thanks!

Comment: The user should not be able to see the files in the appDataFolder.   How would they be moving them?

Comment: @DalmTo well I don't know, but the folder is visible, and the files are also visible on the web interface, which were created by the application. However if the user copies something there, it is not visible for the app.

Comment: Could be this folder is not the "appDataFolder", just a simple folder created by the app? I'm fine with that (even better than a hidden app data folder), but I wan't to see files in it which were created by the user, or at least some method, how the user could grant access to those files to the application.

Comment: I edited the question, it is not the appDataFolder, just a simple folder created by the application.